# OOP to represent mathematical object that has many representation

Tags: c++, oop, software-design

An ellipse can be represented in different ways. there is the representation by means of a center point, semi-axis and a tilt-angle, so five parameters x,y,a,b,phi but we could also have the representation in terms of the conic coefficients A, B, C, D, E, F where the ellipse is defined by Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0. I wondered what would be a good way to represent this as a class in object-oriented programming.

The first way I thought is to have for every ellipse all the data

```
struct EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt {
    // center
    double x0;
    double y0;

    // demi-axis
    double a;
    double b;

    //tilt angle
    double phi;
};

struct EllipseConicCoeff
{
    // the conic is a quadratic given by the general equation ax^2 + 2bx + cy^2 + 2dx + 2fy + g 
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
    double f;
    double g;
};

class Ellipse
{
public:
    Ellipse(EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt centerSemiAxisTilt) : m_centerSemiAxisTilt(centerSemiAxisTilt), m_ConicCoeff(CenterSemiAxisTiltToConicCoeff(centerSemiAxisTilt)) {}
    Ellipse(EllipseConicCoeff ConicCoeff) : m_centerSemiAxisTilt(ConicCoeffToCenterSemiAxisTilt(ConicCoeff)), m_ConicCoeff(ConicCoeff){}

    EllipseConicCoeff CenterSemiAxisTiltToConicCoeff(EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt CenterSemiAxisTilt);
    EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt ConicCoeffToCenterSemiAxisTilt(EllipseConicCoeff ConicCoeff);
private:
    EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt m_centerSemiAxisTilt;
    EllipseConicCoeff m_ConicCoeff;
};
```

But this is somehow unsatisfactory to me since maybe for a particular ellipse we just use one of the two representation.

Another way I thought about is to have a base ellipse class and have two derived classes for each of the representation and then we could define function to convert between them when needed

```
struct EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt {
    // center
    double x0;
    double y0;

    // demi-axis
    double a;
    double b;

    //tilt angle
    double phi;
};

struct EllipseConicCoeff
{
    // the conic is a quadratic given by the general equation ax^2 + 2bx + cy^2 + 2dx + 2fy + g 
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
    double f;
    double g;
};

class EllipseClass
{

};

class EllipseClassConicCoeff : EllipseClass
{
public:
    EllipseClassConicCoeff(EllipseConicCoeff conicCoeff) : m_conicCoeff(conicCoeff) {}
private:
    EllipseConicCoeff m_conicCoeff;
};

class EllipseClassCenterSemiAxisTilt : EllipseClass
{
public:
    EllipseClassCenterSemiAxisTilt(EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt CenterSemiAxisTilt) : m_CenterSemiAxisTilt(CenterSemiAxisTilt) {}
private:
    EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt m_CenterSemiAxisTilt;
};
```

**My question is : What would be an appropriate way to handle such kind of data? (this is just an example, but generally the question is for mathematical objects that may have many representation like the ellipse, complex numbers, or objects for which the conversion is much more)**

Comment: Decide on one representation for your class and write help functions to convert to/from this representation. _"...I thought about is to have a base ellipse class and have two derived classes..."_ - Deriving a class is a _"is a"_ relationship and saying _"an ellipse __is an__ ellipse"_ is a strange relationship.

Comment: Abusing bold font makes text unreadable.

Comment: Did you try (c1,c2,a)? `struct ellipse{std::pair<std:: complex<double>, std::complex<double>> center; double rmax;};`. Suitable implementation depends on most common use case, by the way.

Comment: Pick a representation most suitable for the job and stick with it. If you have a special algorithm with a different preferred representation, convert your data just before feeding it to that algorithm. No OOP is needed at any point. OOP in general is overrated and is best avoided unless you know very well why you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to stay in the C/C++ world and memory management can be important, than I think a std::variant can be a good approach. Here is an example:

```
    struct EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt {
        // center
        double x0;
        double y0;
    
        // demi-axis
        double a;
        double b;
    
        //tilt angle
        double phi;
    };
    
    struct EllipseConicCoeff
    {
        double a;
        double b;
        double c;
        double d;
        double f;
        double g;
    };

int main()
{
    std::variant<EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt, EllipseConicCoeff> e;
   // setting underlying to EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt
   e = EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt{1,2,3,4,5};

   // get value as EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt
   auto foo = std::get<EllipseCenterSemiAxisTilt>(e);

   try
   { // we try to access it as the other struct
      std::get<EllipseConicCoeff>(e);

   } catch (const std::bad_variant_access& ex){} // ops, we can't do that here
   // but we can redefine it
   e = EllipseConicCoeff{1,2,3,4,5,6};
}
```

More info on variant: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: `std::variant` has nothing to do with C world.

Comment: thanks, I didn't knew about std::variant before today!

Comment: `std::variant` is a smarter `union`, so it has to do with C in that regard.